# r code for rolling n dice with elimination

Tags: r

I am trying to write an r code for this challenge: Suppose we roll n dice, remove all the dice that come up 1, and roll the rest again. If we repeat this process, eventually all the dice will be eliminated. How many rolls, on average, will we make?
Here is what I have tried so far but it is not working. The text book theoretical answer for 5 dice is 13.02

## CODE  ATTEMPT

```
N=10000
myfun <- function(...) {
  for(i in list(...)){
  num=1
  S=sample(1:6,i,replace = TRUE)
  i=i-length(which(S==1))
  while(i!=0){
    i=i-length(which(S==1))
    num=num+1
  }
  result[i]=num
}

}

replicate(N,myfun(1:100))
```

Comment: Are the two dice distinguishable or not? So for example, when you say *"all sides appear at least once"*, does that mean "side = 3" from die 1 is different from "side = 3" fro die 2, and both must appear?

Comment: Why did you change the question??? This is now a very different problem (the initial question was a special case of the coupon-collector problem). That's a downvote from me, as I've been working on a solution to your original question. **Please note that people here are willing to help, and completely changing the question after an hour (!) invalidates any attempts made by anyone until that point!**

Comment: I am sorry Maurits Evers. I had erroneously posted the wrong question. I changed it to post the right question for the code I  attempted to write.

Comment: You completely changed the question a full hour (!!) after your initial post! That's *not* how things work around here. Very poor form.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I really hate when folks do that, because it can invalidate all the hard work others have already done.  Fortunately, I was able to salvage part of my original answer in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working script which counts how many times a die must be rolled to generate each of the six values:

```
numRolls <- function() {
    cnt <- 0
    x <- c(1:6)
    while (length(x) > 0) {
        rand <- sample(1:6,1,replace = TRUE)   # generate random value 1 to 6
        x <- x[which(x!=rand)]                 # remove this value if not yet seen
        cnt <- cnt + 1                         # increment number of rolls
    }

    return(cnt)
}

totalRolls <- 0

for (i in 1:1000) {
    totalRolls <- totalRolls + numRolls()
}

totalRolls / 1000
[1] 14.819
```

I ran 1000 tests, and got an average of `14.819` rolls needed to cover every value on a die.

Comment: Dear Tim, sorry I edited the question to match the code I attempted. You may please look at the new question

Comment: @AKUGIZIBWEEDWIN You should still be able to use the function I wrote to get the answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's pretty close to the theoretical value of `n * sum(1 / (1:n)) = 14.7` for `n=6`. Nice! +1

Comment: ...but it's not exact, and I would expect it to be closer for 1000 simulations.  Trying to figure out who is going wrong here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hmm, this might be because the distribution is very right-skewed and 1000 simulations is just not enough. I've added an alternative calculation including a distribution plot to illustrate.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the value you came up with is similar to mine.

Answer (score 2):

To compare with @TimBiegeleisen's answer, here is an alternative approach

We define a function that simulates rolling a 6-sided die, and that returns the minimum number of rolls necessary to get all sides at least once.

```
myfun <- function(Nmax = 10^5) {
    smpl <- sample(1:6, Nmax, replace = T)
    for (n in 1:Nmax) if (length(table(smpl[1:n])) == 6) break;
    return(n)
}
```

We now repeat the process 1000 times

```
set.seed(2018)
x <- replicate(1000, myfun())

summary(x)
#Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
#6.00   10.00   13.00   14.45   17.00   51.00
```

We plot the distribution

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = x), aes(x)) +
    geom_density()
```

[image]

Note that the value is in good agreement with the theoretical value

```
6 * sum(1 / (1:6))
[1] 14.7
```

So the result is close, with an absolute error percentage of

```
abs(mean(x) - 6 * sum(1 / (1:6))) / (6 * sum(1 / (1:6))) * 100
#[1] 1.727891
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the updated code for the above problem

```
N=10000 # number of simulation
    set.seed(1873)
    NoOfRolls<-function(d){
      num=0
      while(d!=0){
        S=sample(1:6,d,replace = TRUE)
        d=d-length(which(S==1)) #Gives difference between number of dice and number of times 1 appears. 
        num=num+1
      }
      return(num)
    }

    Nrolls=replicate(N,NoOfRolls(5))
    hist(Nrolls, breaks=0:60, prob=T)
    mean(Nrolls)#Average changes depending on no of dice thrown. This is the  average for 5 dice.
13.03
```